# closeEvent for Window Python

Tags: python, qml, pyside6

I am creating an application on Qt Creator with python as my backend and I have a problem that i can't seem to pin point.

So what i want to do is have a function called when the user exits the application but the function
`closeEvent(self, event:QCloseEvent)` is never called.

The Constructor that the class inheriting the QMainWindow has is called but the over ridden methods aren't called.

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    id: mainwindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "#000000"
    flags: Qt.Window
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

Connections{
    target: backend
    }
}
```

Main.py

```
    # This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtGui import QCloseEvent
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow

class DetectQuit(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        print("From Constructor")
        super().__init__()
        print("End Constructor")
    
    def hideEvent(self, event):
        print("Minimizing Application")

    def closeEvent(self, event:QCloseEvent) :
        return super().closeEvent(event)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Exiting Application")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    mainwindow=DetectQuit()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend",mainwindow)
    

    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

So what happens is that the `DetectQuit` class' constructor is called but the over-ridden functions are not called. If I add a `self.show()` in the constructor, there appears a second window titled "python" that calls the events accordingly.

Images for Visual assistance :

Running the Application Prints the Constructor part but not the Closing and hiding Events
[image: Running the Application Prints the Constructor part but not the Closing and hiding Events]

This is with the Show method on the class which causes two windows to appear
[image: This is with the Show method on the class which causes two windows to appear]

Closing the second window that popped up causes the expected behaviour
[image: Closing the second window that popped up causes the expected behaviour]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the thing is that the `closeEvent()` does not work so a workaround is that you can add a property to the `Window` Component of the qml that is `onClosing` like:

```
onClosing: {
    print("Exiting Application (1)")
    backend.closeFunction()
}

/*
// close.accepted = false -- if you need to do something else before the window can be closed
onClosing: function(close) {
    print("Exiting Application (1)")
    close.accepted = false
    backend.closeFunction()
}
*/
```

This was Answered by @[ndias](https://forum.qt.io/user/ndias) on the [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/)

Hope this helps.